# Do all events in Javascript capture and bubble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, event-bubbling, event-capturing

I am working on a project where I bind one eventListener to an `<audio>` element for `play` event and another eventListener to its parent element for the same event. I noticed that the child's callback is always called, but the parent's callback is never called.

If I use capture mode of `addEventListener()`, then both callbacks are called normally - first parent, then child.

To further investigate, I wrote a piece of code and found that play event doesn't bubble back to the parent.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><audio src="song.mp3" controls="true"></audio></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent = document.querySelector('div');
    child = document.querySelector('div audio');

    parent.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log('parent-click-capture');}, true);
    parent.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log('parent-click-bubble');}, false);
    parent.addEventListener('play', function() {console.log('parent-play-capture');}, true);
    parent.addEventListener('play', function() {console.log('parent-play-bubble');}, false);

    child.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log('child-click-capture');}, true);
    child.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log('child-click-bubble');}, false);
    child.addEventListener('play', function() {console.log('child-play-capture');}, true);
    child.addEventListener('play', function() {console.log('child-play-bubble');}, false);
</script>
</html>
```

And this was the output:

> parent-click-capture
>       child-click-capture
>       child-click-bubble
>       parent-click-bubble
>       parent-play-capture
>       child-play-capture
>       child-play-bubble

---

Does anyone know if this behaviour is particular only of play event or are there other events that don't enter bubble phase (or capture phase)?

Comment: Not all the events bubbles, you need to check the spec for each event to see whether it supports bubbling

Answer (score 2):

All JS events enter the `capture` phase.

Whether or not an event enters the `bubble` phase can be checked by reading the event's [`bubbles` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles).

```
element.addEventListener('ACTION', (e) => console.log(e.bubbles))
```